# Does the difficulty of Jamestown scale with the number of players involved?

Tags: jamestown

I've played Jamestown a small amount by myself, but mostly with a friend. Most levels are punishingly difficult near the end of the game and I really wouldn't want to try them solo.

This has caused my to wonder: Is the difficulty of levels in Jamestown in anyway affected by multiple players in co-op (aside from obvious affects of TEAMWORK) vs. single player?

Comment: Can't say I know definitively for Jamestown, but in general, co-op shmups increase the health of enemies to correspond to the fact you have twice or more the firepower.

Comment: @GraceNote Unnecessary! Just use friendly fire! :-}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.giantbomb.com/jamestown/61-35611/) on Giant Bomb:

> The enemies also have more health, but just how much isn't explicitly mentioned.

Various user reviews around the internet seem to indicate that the difficulty scales, but the advantage of having more players outweighs the additional difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

I just tested it with 2 players played by my left and right hands respectively.

There aren't any more enemies that I could tell. They seem to have slightly more health as agent86 mentions. Each player only has the current life with the normal number of continues shared collectively but with *revive alls* dropping from destroyed "big" enemies.

Comment: If anything, this makes it sound like the difficulty scales **down**.

Comment: Given how insanely hard the higher difficulties are, I'd wager that as a plus.